# datatables, JSON data from server could not be parsed

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

i'm getting this error :

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.
```

in belowe code. i want to send any parameter for this code for `server_processing.php` and create SQL command with `$_GET`.
this code is showing this result

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"1","iTotalDisplayRecords":"112","aaData":[["\u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0639\u0644\u06cc","\u0645\u062d\u0633\u0646\u06cc","sma_mohseni","2012\/11\/10","50.48.6.52"],["\u0633\u06cc\u062f \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0639\u0644\u06cc","\u0645\u062d\u0633\u0646\u06cc","sma_mohseni","2012\/11\/10","50.48.6.52"]]}
```

[full result is this link](http://paste.debian.net/215201/)

in checked result of json in www.jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com thats alert me json result is VALID

my `server_processing.php` is:

```
<?php

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array('first_name','last_name','login','date','ip'); 

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "date";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = 'SECURITY ';
    $gaSql['password']   = 'SECURITY ';
    $gaSql['db']         = 'SECURITY ';
    $gaSql['server']     = 'SECURITY ';

    /* 
     * MySQL connection
     */
    $gaSql['link'] =  mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) or
        die( 'Could not open connection to server' );

    mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or 
        die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'", $gaSql['link']);            

    /* 
     * Paging
     */

    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }

    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= "`".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ".
                    mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= "`".$aColumns[$i]."` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */

    $sQuery = "SELECT at_members.member_id , at_members.login , at_members.status , at_statistic.date , at_statistic.time , 
          at_statistic.ip , at_members.first_name , at_members.last_name FROM
          ( I'M EDITED THIS LINES FOR SECURITY )
          at_members.status = '{$_GET['$status']}' {$_GET['con']}
          {$_GET['fDate']}  {$_GET['tDate']} 
          {$_GET['nameDore']} ";

    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    // echo $sQuery.'<br/>';

    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div  style="width:100%;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="35%"></th>
                <th width="35%"></th>
                <th width="15%"></th>
                <th width="15%"></th>
                <th width="15%"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using invalid characters, check your result [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Its this one : `\u0645\u062d\u06 33\u0646\u06cc`

You have a space between `u06` and `33`

Also, you might have a problem with the jQuery validation plugin, check [this](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4133/datatables-warning-json-data-from-server-could-not-be-parsed./p1) link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical type of answer, when a script error has happend on your server side script. Try with the chrome web inspector or firebug and the network tab to inspect what result is coming back.

Very likely, there will be something like

```
PHP error foo on line bar
{your: "json", here: "if", it: "only", was: "a warning", and, "not an error"}
```

Comment: jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com alert me json result is VALID

Comment: Validation Result:Valid. my result json is simplified.full result is this http://paste.debian.net/215201/